# How do I extract characters from a file name in the Imagemagick convert command line

Tags: windows, text, imagemagick

I would like to modify the following command so that the date variables are populated from the filename.

Example: The 020299-INF-A-0922015.JPG should cause the *year* variable to have the value 2015.

command:

```
convert 020299-I*.jpg^
 -set filename:oldname "%t"^
 -set month "MM"^
 -set day "DD"^
 -set year "YYYY"^
 -fill red -density 180 -pointsize 60^
 -gravity south -annotate +0+0 "%t"^
 -gravity northwest -annotate +0+0 "%[month]/%[day]/%[year]"^
 .\annotated\%[filename:oldname].png
```

Comment: How are we to know which part of the filename to take the month and day from?

Comment: Take your pick. Its an example. However, the month happens to be the first two chars of the last chunck of digits and the day is the digits between the month and the year.

Answer (score 0):

I've lost the will to live doing stupid Windows BATCH stuff, but you can do it something like this:

```
@echo off
REM Start with your filename
set f=020299-INF-A-0922015.JPG

REM Parse out last chunk, splitting on dashes and dots selecting 4th field
for /f "tokens=4 delims=-." %%a in ("%f%") do set chunk=%%a
echo.%chunk%

REM Take last 4 digits of "chunk" as year
set year=%chunk:~-4%
echo.%year%

REM Take first 2 characters of "chunk" as month
set month=%chunk:~0,2%
echo.%month%

REM Strip year off "chunk", leaving md=month and day part
set md=%chunk:~0,-4%
echo.%md%
REM Take last one or two characters of "md" as day
set day=%md:~2,2%
echo %day%
```

**Output**

```
09222015
2015
09
2
```

I worked out all the above using [DOSTips.com](http://www.dostips.com/DtTipsStringManipulation.php).